# How to remove and keep duplicate word in a list in python

Tags: python

Here is the original list:
Liste = ['hello','hello world','nice world','nice'] and I want to remove the duplicate words in that list and save the non duplicate words in a list.
so the result List will be like this:  ['hello', world', 'nice']
So anyone can help me? Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this answer I didn't use list comprehensions as it would be too hard for the author to understand, judging the difficulty of the question, it's safe to assume that he's fairly new.

```
duped_list = ['hello','hello world','nice world','nice']

def cleanse(duped_list):
    cleansed = []
    for words in duped_list:
        for word in words.split():
            if word not in cleansed:
                cleansed.append(word)
    return cleansed
```

Answer (score 3):

`list({ww: 1 for w in [f.split(' ') for f in foo] for ww in w})`

relies on dicts preserving the insertion order.

Comment: @fsimonjetz good point. I'd argue it's clearer with it there, but that's at odds with the rest of my answer :-)